# Get remainder from re.findall

Tags: python, string, parsing

Whats the best way to get the remainder from re.findall?

for example:

```
string = "abcdefghijklmnop"
list = re.findall('.{5}', string)
```

output:

```
['abcde', 'fghij', 'klmno']
```

'p' will be left out.  Whats the best way to get 'p' or the remainder of the string

or is there a better way to divide it in chunks?

Comment: You could modify your regex to `.{1,5}`

Comment: there is no "remainder" from re.findall, since findall doesn't require the matches to be contiguous; if you want whatever wasn't matched, you can either manually remove each match from the string until you are left with the unmatched portion, or you can rewrite your expression to extract repeating groups of exactly 5 characters, with a final optional group from 0 to 4 characters.

Comment: that works well.  Thanks!